# Repository fails to list objects from h2 db`s table during integration testing in srping boot

Tags: junit4, spring-boot-test

Can someone explain why during integration testing my repository does not see entities in my in-memory h2 tables?
It is my testing class ^

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@Scope(value = "prototype")
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class ShkiMonitorService extends Thread {

    private final Environment env;

    private final BotService barcodesDataService;

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public ShkiMonitorService(Environment env,
                              BotService botService,
                              @Qualifier("myRestTemplate") RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.env = env;
        this.barcodesDataService = botService;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    private boolean isThreadRunning = true;

   
    public void stopProcessing() {
        this.isThreadRunning = false;
    }

    public boolean isThreadRunning() {
        return this.isThreadRunning;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        log.info("ShkiMonitor service started. Time - {}", LocalDateTime.now());

        boolean botProcessedLastData = true;

        while (this.isThreadRunning) {
            long timeStart = System.nanoTime();
            log.info("ShkiMonitor processing started, time - {}", LocalDateTime.now());

            List<ShkiMonitoring> botShkiBarcodes = barcodesDataService.getAllBarcodesShki(); /
       }
   }
}
```

This is a service which is used in the class above :

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class BotService {

    private final ShkiRepository repository;

    private final ShkiPreviousDataRepository previousDataRepository;

    public BotService(ShkiRepository repository, ShkiPreviousDataRepository previousDataRepository) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.previousDataRepository = previousDataRepository;
    }

    public List<ShkiMonitoring> getAllBarcodesShki() {
        return this.repository.getAll();
    }
}
```

And my reposotiry bean :

```
@Repository
public interface ShkiRepository extends JpaRepository<ShkiMonitoring, ShkiMonitoringIdClass> {

    @Query(value = "select * from public.shki_monitoring", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ShkiMonitoring> getAll();
}
```

For testing i used the following test class (in AppConfig.class i creat a RestTemplate bean for my app) :

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(value = {ShkiMonitorService.class, BotService.class, AppConfig.class})
@DataJpaTest(showSql = false)
@AutoConfigureDataJpa
@AutoConfigurationPackage(basePackages = {"ua.ukrposhta"})
@TestPropertySource(locations = {
        "classpath:application-test.properties", "classpath:hibernate-test.properties"
})
@SqlGroup({
        @Sql(value = "classpath:sql/shki_monitoring.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD),
        @Sql(value = "classpath:sql/shki_prev_data.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Slf4j
@MockBean(value = {RestTemplate.class})
class ShkiMonitorServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ShkiMonitorService service;
    @Autowired
    private BotService botService;
    @Autowired
    private ShkiRepository repoShki;

@Test
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Rollback
    void run_botShkiBarcodes_not_empty_bot_response_200() throws InterruptedException{
        String barcode_1 = "1401707915585";
        String barcode_2 = "SK353309503LV";
        String barcode_3 = "RK102746742LV";

        List<ShkiMonitoring> list = repoShki.findAll();
        list.forEach(sm -> log.info("{}", sm.toString()));
        
        List<ShkiMonitoring> newList = botService.getAllBarcodesShki();
        newList.forEach(sm -> log.info("{}", sm.toString()));

        service.start();
        service.join();
}
```

So the problem is in next - when i run this test method botShkiBarcodes_not_empty_bot_response_200() and my repoShki or botService do the getAll() and getAllBarcodesShki() methods, I see , that they give me a list of objects from my h2 db where these objects were inserted using the @sql annotation.
But inside the ShkiMonitorService class, this part of code :
List botShkiBarcodes = barcodesDataService.getAllBarcodesShki();
gives me an empty botShkiBarcodes list of objects.
I do not understand what i am doing wrong.
Please, help me.